# What are the ways to obtain public key of a wallet with no outputs

Tags: transactions, public-key

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain public key of a public address where the address does not have any output transaction

Comment: Are you looking for the public key to your own address or someone else's?

Comment: I'm looking for the public key of the btc puzzle

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about a Pay to Public Key Hash (P2PKH) address.

[Cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) have the *pre-image resistance* property:

> Given a hash value `h`, it should be difficult to find a message `m` for which `h = hash(m)`.

P2PKH addresses encode a locking script that commits funds to the hash of a public key. Given that the address only provides the hash, it is not possible to guess the public key from the address as that would require breaking the *pre-image resistance* property of RIPEMD-160.

Comment: So it is not possible to get the public key?

Comment: No, you cannot learn the original value if you only have a hash.